# How to share Python method between two Django classes?

Tags: python, django

I have two classes in my Django models.py file:

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def create_profile(self, user, member):
        # Set default age to 100 years old when profile is created.
        years_ago100 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=101 * 365)
        age = calculate_age(years_ago100)       # <- Used here
        profile = self.create(user=user, person_dob=years_ago100, person_age=age)
        return

class Profile(models.Model):
    person_dob = models.DateField()
    person_age = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # Update to real age when user edits profile for the first time.
      self.person_age = calculate_age(self.person_dob)    # <- Used here too
      super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Each class uses this calculate_age method:

```
def calculate_age(born):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return (today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)))
```

How can I make this method accessible to both classes?  One easy way would be to make the method global like this but that seems like a kludgy way to do it:

```
def calculate_age(born):
  ...

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
  ...

class Profile(models.Model):
  ...
```

Also, this wouldn't work if I wanted to access that method outside of this particular models module.  Is there a standard way to do this when using Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you consider it kludgy. It's often done and PyCharm even makes it convenient, when it detects that a method doesn't access class members and thus can be turned into either a static method or a function.

On top of that, Python importing is extremely convenient. Yes, you can access a module function from outside the module and the syntax is the same as accessing a class: the member is accessed through dot references.

module:

```py
# myapp/utils.py

def calculate_age(born):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return (today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)))
```

```py
#otherapp/models.py
from myapp import utils

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        if utils.calculate_age(self.birthday) < 13:
            raise ValidationError("no minors below 13 allowed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the function calculate_age into a different file, then import it at the top of your models.py file. This would allow access to all classes/methods/functions inside.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like multiple inheritance? Not really sure this would be better than a global function for what your doing

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    person_dob = models.DateField()
    person_age = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Update to real age when user edits profile for the first time.
        self.person_age = self.calculate_age(self.person_dob)    # <- Used here too
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def calculate_age(born):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return (today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)))


class ProfileManager(models.Manager, Profile):
    def create_profile(self, user, member):
        # Set default age to 100 years old when profile is created.
        years_ago100 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=101 * 365)
        age = self.calculate_age(years_ago100)       # <- Used here
        profile = self.create(user=user, person_dob=years_ago100, person_age=age)
        return
```

And if you don't like inheriting the entire models.Model from your Profile class you can make a shared class they can both inherit from.

```
class Profile(models.Model, helpers):
    person_dob = models.DateField()
    person_age = models.IntegerField()

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Update to real age when user edits profile for the first time.
        self.person_age = self.calculate_age(self.person_dob)    # <- Used here too
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class ProfileManager(models.Manager, helpers):
    def create_profile(self, user, member):
        # Set default age to 100 years old when profile is created.
        years_ago100 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=101 * 365)
        age = self.calculate_age(years_ago100)       # <- Used here
        profile = self.create(user=user, person_dob=years_ago100, person_age=age)
        return


class helpers():
    def calculate_age(self, born):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return (today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)))

    def other_shared_method(self):
        pass
```